# Self-Hosted Github runner, how do privileged commands work?

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, sudo, github, cp

What I'm trying to achieve:

A fully automated deployment for a React App, on any commit to the `live` branch, by my own defined Github Runner, which is running `Ubuntu Server 20.04`, with `npm 6.14.8`

What I have so far:

`autodeploy.yml`

```yml
name: AutoDeploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [live]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Deploy Client App
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12'
        
    - name: Fetch latest version
      uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: npm install
      working-directory: ./Code/client-app-react

    - name: Build project
      run: npm run build
      working-directory: ./Code/client-app-react

    - name: Copy build to webserver
      run: sudo cp -r ./ /var/www/domains/react.app.public
      working-directory: ./Code/client-app-react/build

    - name: Copy .htaccess to webserver
      run: sudo cp .htaccess /var/www/domains/react.app.public/.htaccess
      working-directory: ./Media/Server
```

Everything seems to work until I get to the Copy/Paste step by

```sh
sudo cp -r ./ /var/www/domains/react.app.public
```

The message I get is:

```sh
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have no clue of what AskPass is or how to open a TTY. I expected this to work according to this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830375/github-actions-workflow-error-permission-denied

How do I execute privileged or elevated commands from the Github Action configuration file `autodeploy.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Change permissions of `/var/www/domains/react.app.public` directory so that the user can write into the directory. Then you can remove the `sudo` away from the command.
2. Configure `sudo` to not ask password when executing the command. This can be implemented with the following line in `/etc/sudoers.d/autodeploy`

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cp -r ./ /var/www/domains/react.app.public
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cp .htaccess /var/www/domains/react.app.public/.htaccess
```

Here the `user` is the name of the user that runs the deployment process.